# What are "attack" Spells?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In the rules, it says

> Attacking a monster does not require making an evade test.  This
>   attack may be unarmed, with a weapon, or with an **“attack”  Spell card**.
>   This attack does not need to target a monster in the  investigator’s
>   space.

You can avoid the evade test if casting an attack spell. So what spells are considered "attack" spells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bind Monster** and **Shriveling** are both Attack Spells.  Just under the title of the card is the phrase, *Spell, Attack*.

Bind Monster will stun the target while Shriveling will do a good amount of damage if you pass the test to cast them.

Gloria Goldberg can start with Bind Monster while Harvey Walters can start with Shriveling.  Otherwise you will have to gain the spells during play by reading a tome.